# Using Watir to verify strike tag exists in html

Tags: ruby, xpath, watir

I have the following html code below that I am using watir to try and verify that March is not have a strike tag and April, June, and July do have strike tag.  I'm pretty sure xpath is the key to my answer but have failed at coming up with right solution.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
<div class="availability">
Available:
    <ul>
     <li><span class="month available">March</span></li>
     <li><span class="month unavailable"><strike>April</strike></span></li>
     <li><span class="month unavailable"><strike>May</strike></span></li>
     <li><span class="month unavailable"><strike>June</strike></span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using watir-webdriver, you can do:

```
#Create an array of the strike elements
months_with_strike = browser.elements(:tag_name, 'strike').collect(&:text)

#Determine if the specified month is in the array
months_with_strike.include?('March')
#=> false
months_with_strike.include?('April')
#=> true
```

Alternatively, if you only want to check for a single element:

```
browser.element(:tag_name => 'strike', :text => 'March').exists?
#=> false
browser.element(:tag_name => 'strike', :text => 'April').exists?
#=> true
```

The important part is that you can get custom elements by using the `:tag_name` as a locator.

Note: I would think this should also work in watir-classic, but for some reason I am getting exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

**Use (assuming the initial context node is the parent of the `div` element)**:

```
div/ul/li/span[not(strike)]
```

This selects any `span` elements that doesn't have a `strike` child (and is a child of a `li` that is a child of a `ul` that is a child of a `div` that is a child of the initial context node)

**And use**:

```
div/ul/li/span[strike]
```

This selects any `span` elements that has a `strike` child (and is a child of a `li` that is a child of a `ul` that is a child of a `div` that is a child of the initial context node)

**XSLT - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:copy-of select="div/ul/li/span[not(strike)]"/>
==============  
     <xsl:copy-of select="div/ul/li/span[strike]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied to the provided XML document:**

```
<div class="availability">
Available:
    <ul>
     <li><span class="month available">March</span></li>
     <li><span class="month unavailable"><strike>April</strike></span></li>
     <li><span class="month unavailable"><strike>May</strike></span></li>
     <li><span class="month unavailable"><strike>June</strike></span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**the two XPath expressions are evaluated and the results (selected nodes) are copied to the output, delimited by a visually distinctive delimiter string:**

```
<span class="month available">March</span>
==============  
<span class="month unavailable">
   <strike>April</strike>
</span>
<span class="month unavailable">
   <strike>May</strike>
</span>
<span class="month unavailable">
   <strike>June</strike>
</span>
```